# Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method - At rowcount 0

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a VBA script that runs through a bank statement finding payments of a certain value.  This code ran when I wrote it, but a couple of months later I get Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method; here is an extract of the code.

```
Set bankWB = ActiveWorkbook 
Set bankWS = ActiveSheet 

For rowcount = 0 To 250 
skipline = False
If bankWS.Cells(rowcount, paidcol) = 5 Then
    payee = Trim(bankWS.Cells(rowcount, payeecol))
    paid = "5"
```

The error occurs on the 'if' line.

I've found various examples that reference cell values in the same way and this worked previously.  If you Google this error there are lots of results and I see that using 'range' is more common than using 'cell' to reference a single cell, but it's not obvious to me how to easily translate my (x,y) cell variables/loop into a range "A1" type value so I've not tried rewriting the code to use range instead yet.

I assume that the object is bankWS.Cells and it's the property rather than the method that is the problem. I want to know what the value of the object is (=property), I'm not trying to do anything with the object (=method)

I've seen lots of different ways of writing the cell object, and tried various permutations, none of which make a difference. eg.

```
If worksheet.bankWS.Cells(rowcount, paidcol) = 5 Then
If bankWS.Cells.item(rowcount, paidcol) = 5 Then
If bankWS.Cells(rowcount, paidcol).value = 5 Then
```

I'm thinking that the code is ok, and that something else has changed.

---

#### Solved

Thanks to @99moorem my row count loop should have started at 1, not 0, there will be no cell(0,1).

Comment: is rowcount 0 when you get the error? What is also in paidcol when you get the error

Comment: Are you sure your active sheet isn't a chart sheet?

Comment: @99moorem Rowcount would have a value of 0 to start (perhaps I should start with a value of 1). I'll try that.  PaidCol has a value of 6.  Yes, you are right to question this. I started the count with 1 and it works, and that makes sense, there will be no cell(0,1).

Comment: I find this slightly odd. When I type ?activesheet.cells(0,1).value in the immediate window I get Run time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error rather than Run time error '438'. I thus thought that Rory's guess was likely correct, but Martin seems to suggest that it is (in effect) a subscript out of range sort of error after all. I still don't understand how the error he described generated the error code he gave.